# How to test whether a binary string is valid UTF8?

Tags: go, utf-8

https://github.com/google/codesearch/blob/master/index/write.go#L581

I see the above to test whether two bytes can appear in a valid UTF8 string. But I don't understand how it works. Could anybody help me understand why this function works? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) for a description of the encoding. The encoding is:

```
num
bytes 1st byte  2nd byte  3rd byte  4 byte
1     0xxxxxxx          
2     110xxxxx  10xxxxxx        
3     1110xxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx  
4     11110xxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

To help make the code easier to compare the the wikipedia article, here's the code with `< n` rewritten to `<= n-1` and integer literals rewritten to binary integer literals.

```
func validUTF8(c1, c2 uint32) bool {
    switch {
    case c1 <= 0b01111111:
        // 1-byte, must be followed by 1-byte or first of multi-byte
        return c2 <= 0b01111111 || 0b11000000 <= c2 && c2 <= 0b11110111
    case c1 <= 0b10111111:
        // continuation byte, can be followed by nearly anything
        return c2 <= 0b11110111
    case c1 <= 0b11110111:
        // first of multi-byte, must be followed by continuation byte
        return 0b10000000 <= c2 && c2 <= 0b10111111
    }
    return false
}
```

The first case checks the byte following a 1-byte encoding (0xxxxxxx).

The second case checks the byte following a continuation byte (10xxxxxx).

The third case checks the byte following the start of a multi-byte encoding (110xxxxx, 1110xxxx, 11110xxx).

The function reports whether two bytes can be in a valid UTF-8 encoding. A sequence of valid byte pairs is not necessarily a valid UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Using the standard library's [`unicode/utf8`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8) module is probably better suited for your task than using that function. Check out [`utf8.Valid`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#Valid) documentation.

Comment: Probably not, because the entire string may not be in the memory. The code reads bytes from a text file into a buffer of a fixed size chunk by chunk, some UFT8 character may only be partially in the buffer. So it has to be checked every two bytes.

Comment: You can stil lleverage `utf8.Valid` for this, calling it on every two bytes. A better solution (performance-wise) might be working on chunks of your string (taking edge cases into account). Anyway consider taking advantage of `utf8.Valid` or its [source code](https://golang.org/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go).

Comment: Could you explain how this code work? If I have a valid UTF8 string in byte array, and I truncate the byte array in the middle and keep the part before the trunction, is the kept part still valid according to the `Valid()` function?